# ArrayPlot: space between displayed data and frame

Tags: plotting, spacing

When I execute the lines

```
data1 = Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 1}];
data10 = Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, ImagePadding -> 25};
bothPlots = Row[{ArrayPlot[data1, opts], ArrayPlot[data10, opts]}]
```

I get the following picture:

[image]

The space between plot data and frame of the 1x10 array is much smaller than the space between the plot data and frame of the 10x10 matrix. Is there a possibility to avoide that or to set that space manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be fixed by specifying the `PlotRangePadding` option:

```
data1 = Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 1}];
data10 = Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
   ImagePadding -> 25, PlotRangePadding -> .2};
bothPlots = Row[{ArrayPlot[data1, opts], ArrayPlot[data10, opts]}]
```

[image: padding]